# как передать значение в контексте вызова для одного обьекта

Tags: jquery

При выборе времени доставки пытаюсь передать значение в тултипе, в данном случае  это время -> кликнуть "выбрать время", При выборе я записываю это в это же поле выбранное значение. Подскажите как передать значение только для одного обьекта(DOM-элемента(селектора)).

```js
$(".time-range__selected, .close_tooltip").on("click", function(e) {


       $(".time-range__tooltip").addClass("dnone");
       var toolTip = $(this).parent().next(".time-range__tooltip");
       if (toolTip.hasClass("dnone")) {
         toolTip.removeClass("dnone");

         var firstClick = true;
         $(document).bind("click.myEvent", function(e) {
           if (!firstClick && $(e.target).closest(".time-range__tooltip").length == 0) {
             toolTip.addClass("dnone");
             $(document).unbind("click.myEvent");
           }
           firstClick = false;
         });
       }

       e.preventDefault();

     });
     $(".time-radio").on("click", function(e) {
       var newTimeRangeText = $(this).next().text();

       $(".time-range__selected").text(newTimeRangeText);
     })
```

```css
   
#order_form label {
  color: #656565;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#order_form .chosubmission label {
  text-align: center;
}
#order_form input[type="text"],
#order_form input[type="email"],
#order_form textarea,
#order_form select {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
#order_form .control-group .controls {
  display: inline;
}

#order_form .control-label {
  padding-top: 3px;
}
label span.required,
.control-label span.required {
  color: #b94a48;
}
#chodelmethod {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.chotab_content {
  font-size: 12px;
}
table.chodeltable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
table.chodeltable td {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 9px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.chodeltable th {
  color: #656565;
  font-weight: normal;
}
td.tablebold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#chopaymethod {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 414px;
}
#chopaymethod_chosen .chosen-search {
  display: none;
}
.payoptionsimgs {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 225px;
}
.payoptionsimgs img {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.choinfoblock {
  background: #f6f6f6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px 10px 20px;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.choinfoblocktitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.chosubmission {
  color: #656565;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
.chosubmission a {
  color: #d22100;
}
#termsagreement {
  margin: 10px 0 30px;
}
.chosubmitbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#order_form .paytypes .controls {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#order_form .paytypes .control-label {
  float: left;
}
#order_form .paytypes label.radio {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
padding: 10px 10px 10px 45px;
}
span.chotab a.pick_up {
  color: #656565;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span.choactive a.pick_up {
  color: #d22100;
}
.hiddenblock {
  display: none;
}

#order_form .chosubmission label {
  text-align: center; 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#order_form .chosubmission label input {
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.chosubmission .form-actions input[type="submit"] {
  background: #be3d23;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #be3d23 0%, #b43a22 25%, #96321d 72%, #882e1d 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #be3d23 0%, #b43a22 25%, #96321d 72%, #882e1d 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #be3d23 0%, #b43a22 25%, #96321d 72%, #882e1d 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#be3d23', endColorstr='#882e1d', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  left: -28px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.choinfoblock.chosubmission .col-md-4 {
  width: auto;
}
.choinfoblock.chosubmission .col-md-8 {
  width: 100%;
}
.control-group.delivery-loader {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
}
.delivery {
  /*border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;*/
  display: inline-block;
}
.column-1 {
  /*width: 190px;*/
  width: 50%;
}
.column-2,
.column-3 {
  with: 115px;
}
.delivery__table {
  display: table;
}
.delivery__row {
  display: table-row;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #656565;
}
.delivery__table .delivery__row:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.delivery__cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.delivery {
  display: block;
}
.h_row {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
.h_row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.time-range-tooltip {
  list-style: none;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked),
input[name="offer[]"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label {
  color: #a32b25;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: url("../images/old-chekbox.png") no-repeat 0 -13px;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../images/old-chekbox.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 1px;
  /*font-size: 16px;*/
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #656565;
  transition: all .2s;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
input[name="offer[]"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[name="offer[]"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
input[name="offer[]"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/*new radiobutton style*/

input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;   
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  font-size: 11px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)*/
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  background: #144865;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 4px;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:before,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:after,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled + label,
input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.choinfoblock .control-group .control-label {
  width: 30%;
}
.choinfoblock .control-group .control-label + div,
.row.delivery-group .delivdata {
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.row.delivery-group .control-label {
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.o-date,
.choose-time {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: -2px;
}
.o-date {
  background: url(../images/date-icon.png) no-repeat;
}
.choose-time {
  background: url(../images/clock-ico.png) no-repeat;
}
.c-date,
.time-range__wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
.o-time {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ch-time,
.del-link {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #969595 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.day,
.date {
  color: #656565;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ch-time::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.under-line {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}
.day::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.date::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.del-link {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #969595;
}
.del-link {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: -7px;
}
.time-range__wrap {
  position: relative;
}
/*.change-time + .time-range__tooltip {
 display: block;
}
.no-change-time + .time-range__tooltip {
 display: none;
}*/

.dnone {
  display: none;
}
.cal {
  dispaly: block;
}
.c-date input[type="button"] {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #656565;
}
.choose-date {
  line-height: 21px;
}
.time-range__tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #969595;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 115px;
  top: -5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 110px;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 4;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
}
.time-range__tooltip::before {
  content: "";
  left: -16px;
  top: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid #f6f6f6;
  z-index: 6;
}
.time-range__tooltip::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #969595;
  z-index: 5;
  left: -16px;
  top: 8px;
}
.time-range__selected {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.time-range__selected {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #969595;
  color: #969595;
}
/*modal choose time*/

.ch-time__modal {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  width: 102px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: -25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-bordfer-radius: 3px;
}
.ch-time__modal::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
  left: -19px;
  bottom: 83px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #f6f6f6;
  z-index: 6;
}
.ch-time__modal::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
  left: -21px;
  bottom: 82px;
  border: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid #e0e0e0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.ch-time__wrapcontent {
  position: relative;
}
.hasDatepicker {
  display: initial;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .choinfoblock {
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
  }
  .choinfoblock .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .choinfoblock input[type="text"],
  .choinfoblock input[type="email"],
  .choinfoblock textarea,
  .choinfoblock select {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .delivery-group .control-label {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .delivery-group .delivdata {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .chotab_content .delivery .delivery__row:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
  }
  .delivery__cell {
    float: left;
  }
  /*.mobile .column-2 {
  display: none;
 }*/
  /*.data-range-mobile {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%;
     float: left;
 }*/
  .open-calendar,
  .time-range__wrap {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .column-3 {
    display: none;
  }
  .column-1a {
    display: block;
  }
  .delivery__cell {
    padding: 5px 7px 5px 0;
  }
  .column-1 {
    width: auto;
  }
  .column-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .time-range__wrap {
    /*float: right;*/
    /*padding-right: 10%;*/
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  .open-calendar {
    padding-left: 7%;
  }
  .day::after,
  .date::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .column-1 {
    /*width: 150px;*/
    width: 70%;
  }
  .del-link {
    top: 0;
  }
  .del-link::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .time-range__tooltip {
    top: 36px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .time-range__tooltip::before {
    left: 45px;
    top: -20px;
    border-right: none;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #f6f6f6;
  }
  .time-range__tooltip::after {
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #969595;
    left: 44px;
    top: -22px;
  }
  .main-column {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .choinfoblock {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .row.control-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #order_form .control-label {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .choinfoblock,
  .choinfoblock .control-group .control-label {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .choinfoblock .control-group .control-label + div,
  .row.delivery-group .delivdata {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group > .control-label {
    display: none;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group > .control-label + div > label {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  #order_form .chosubmission label {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
  .offer__inner {
    margin-left: 3px;
  }
  .br-oi {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .chosubmission .form-actions input[type="submit"] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .row.delivery-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .chotab_item {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }
  #order_form input[type="text"],
  #order_form input[type="email"],
  #order_form textarea,
  #order_form select {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
   
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .delivery__table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .time-range__wrap {
    top: -8px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .column-1a {
    display: none;
  }
  .del-link::after,
  .day::after,
  .date::after {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .open-calendar {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
.delivery-group .control-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #656565;
}
.type_pay__sub-info {
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: grey;
  line-height: 12px;
}
.paytypes .type-pay {
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.choinfoblock.paytypes {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
}
.paytypes .control-group {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.type-pay__inner {
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #303030;
}
.choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group > .control-label {
  display: none;
}
.rules_ofert {
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group .control-label + div {
  width: 100%;
}
.br-oi {
  display: none;
}
.chotab_item {
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.chotabs > .chotab.pick_upcho:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chotab_content">
    <div class="delivery radio">
      <div class="delivery__table">

        <div class="delivery__row">
          <div class="delivery__cell h_row column-1">Способы доставки</div>
          <div class="delivery__cell h_row column-2">Сроки доставки</div>
          <div class="delivery__cell h_row column-3">Стоимость</div>
        </div>
        <div class="empty__row">

        </div>
        <div class="delivery__row">
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1">
            <input id="select__delivery-k" class="delivery_methods" name="delivery" type="radio">
            <label for="select__delivery-k">Доставка 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1a">
            250 руб.
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-2">
            <div class="open-calendar">
              <a class="c-date">
                <i class="o-date"></i>
                <input class="choose-date" type="button" value="Сегодня">
                <div class="under-line"></div>



              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="time-range__wrap">
              <div class="time-range">
                <i class="choose-time"></i>
                <span class="time-range__selected">Выбрать время</span>
              </div>

              <ul class="time-range__tooltip dnone">
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-1" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-1">10.00-18.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-2" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-2">18.00-21.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-3" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-3">10.00-15.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-4" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-4">14.00-18.00</label>
                </li>
                <a class="close_tooltip">закрыть</a>
              </ul>

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="delivery__cell column-3">
            250 руб.
          </div>




        </div>

        <div class="delivery__row">
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1">
            <input id="select__delivery-s" class="delivery_methods" name="delivery" type="radio">
            <label for="select__delivery-s">Доставка 2</label>
          </div>

          <div class="delivery__cell column-1a">
            500 руб.
          </div>

          <div class="delivery__cell column-2">
            <div class="open-calendar">
              <a class="c-date">
                <i class="o-date"></i>
                <input class="choose-date" type="button" value="Сегодня">
                <div class="under-line"></div>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="time-range__wrap">
              <div class="time-range">
                <i class="choose-time"></i>
                <span class="time-range__selected" href="">Выбрать время</span>
              </div>

              <ul class="time-range__tooltip dnone">
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-5" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-5">10.00-18.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-6" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-6">18.00-21.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-7" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-7">10.00-15.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-8" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-8">14.00-18.00</label>
                </li>

                <a class="close_tooltip">закрыть</a>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-3">
            500 руб.
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="delivery__row svz">
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1">
            <input id="select__delivery-sv" class="delivery_methods" name="delivery" type="radio">
            <label for="select__delivery-sv">доставка3</label>
            <a class="chotab pick_upcho del-link where-to-get">Выбрать магазин</a>
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1a">
            Бесплатно
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-2">
            <div class="open-calendar">
              <a class="c-date">
                <i class="o-date"></i>
                <input class="choose-date" type="button" value="Сегодня">
                <div class="under-line"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="delivery__cell column-3">
            Бесплатно
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="delivery__row">
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1">
            <input id="select__delivery-pvz" class="delivery_methods" name="delivery" type="radio">
            <label for="select__delivery-pvz">Доставка 4</label>
            <a class="chotab pick_upcho del-link where-to-get">Выбрать ПВЗ</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-1a">
            от 90 руб
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-2">
            <div class="open-calendar">
              <a class="c-date">
                <i class="o-date"></i>
                <input class="choose-date" type="button" value="Сегодня">
                <div class="under-line"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-3">
            от 90 руб.
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: вообще непонятно что и куда нужно передать, что в данном случае понимается под контекстом?

Comment: Вопрос малопонятен. А лишней информации в нем слишком много, что туманит мой хрустальный шар. Шанс получить ответ значительно увеличится, если Вы склеите минимальный пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох у вас и каша, фетиш для верстальщика

Решается так:

```
    $(".time-radio").on("click", function(e) {
        var newTimeRangeText = $(this).next().text();
        $(this).parents('.time-range__wrap').find('.time-range__selected').text(newTimeRangeText);

    });
```

Короче он хочет чтобы время в каждом блоке выбиралось индивидуально. Полный код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #order_form label {
      color: #656565;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 12px;
      /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
      margin-right: 10px;
      text-align: right;
      width: 100%;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    #order_form .chosubmission label {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #order_form input[type="text"],
    #order_form input[type="email"],
    #order_form textarea,
    #order_form select {
      background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 13px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      line-height: 25px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #order_form .control-group .controls {
      display: inline;
    }
    #order_form .control-label {
      padding-top: 3px;
    }
    label span.required,
    .control-label span.required {
      color: #b94a48;
    }
    #chodelmethod {
      background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      line-height: 25px;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .chotab_content {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    table.chodeltable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    table.chodeltable td {
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      padding: 9px;
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    table.chodeltable th {
      color: #656565;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    td.tablebold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #chopaymethod {
      background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 13px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      width: 414px;
    }
    #chopaymethod_chosen .chosen-search {
      display: none;
    }
    .payoptionsimgs {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left: 225px;
    }
    .payoptionsimgs img {
      margin-right: 15px;
    }
    .choinfoblock {
      background: #f6f6f6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      margin: 0 auto 30px;
      padding: 15px 30px 10px 20px;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
    .choinfoblocktitle {
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .chosubmission {
      color: #656565;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .chosubmission a {
      color: #d22100;
    }
    #termsagreement {
      margin: 10px 0 30px;
    }
    .chosubmitbtn {
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #order_form .paytypes .controls {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #order_form .paytypes .control-label {
      float: left;
    }
    #order_form .paytypes label.radio {
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    padding:10px 10px 10px 45px;
  }
  span.chotab a.pick_up {
    color: #656565;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  span.choactive a.pick_up {
    color: #d22100;
  }
  .hiddenblock {
    display: none;
  }
  #order_form .chosubmission label {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #order_form .chosubmission label input {
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  }
  .chosubmission .form-actions input[type="submit"] {
    background: #be3d23;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #be3d23 0%, #b43a22 25%, #96321d 72%, #882e1d 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #be3d23 0%, #b43a22 25%, #96321d 72%, #882e1d 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #be3d23 0%, #b43a22 25%, #96321d 72%, #882e1d 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#be3d23', endColorstr='#882e1d', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    left: -28px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission .col-md-4 {
    width: auto;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission .col-md-8 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .control-group.delivery-loader {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
  }
  .delivery {
    /*border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;*/
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .column-1 {
    /*width: 190px;*/
    width: 50%;
  }
  .column-2,
  .column-3 {
    with: 115px;
  }
  .delivery__table {
    display: table;
  }
  .delivery__row {
    display: table-row;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #656565;
  }
  .delivery__table .delivery__row:nth-of-type(2)::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .delivery__cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 7px;
  }
  .delivery {
    display: block;
  }
  .h_row {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
  }
  .h_row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
  .time-range-tooltip {
    list-style: none;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked),
  input[name="offer[]"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label,
  input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label {
    color: #a32b25;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
  input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: url("../images/old-chekbox.png") no-repeat 0 -13px;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
  input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("../images/old-chekbox.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 1px;
    /*font-size: 16px;*/
    line-height: 0.8;
    color: #656565;
    transition: all .2s;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
  input[name="offer[]"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #bbb;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
    color: #999;
  }
  input[name="offer[]"]:disabled + label {
    color: #aaa;
  }
  /*new radiobutton style*/
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
  }
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)*/
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    content: "";
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    background: #144865;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 4px;
    line-height: 0.8;
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:before,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #bbb;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:after,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
    color: #999;
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:disabled + label,
  input.time-radio[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
    color: #aaa;
  }
  input.delivery_methods[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: #000 !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
  }
  .choinfoblock .control-group .control-label {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .choinfoblock .control-group .control-label + div,
  .row.delivery-group .delivdata {
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .row.delivery-group .control-label {
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .o-date,
  .choose-time {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: -2px;
  }
  .o-date {
    background: url(../images/date-icon.png) no-repeat;
  }
  .choose-time {
    background: url(../images/clock-ico.png) no-repeat;
  }
  .c-date,
  .time-range__wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .o-time {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .ch-time,
  .del-link {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #969595 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .day,
  .date {
    color: #656565;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .ch-time::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  .under-line {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 14px;
  }
  .day::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .date::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #656;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .del-link {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #969595;
  }
  .del-link {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: -7px;
  }
  .time-range__wrap {
    position: relative;
  }
  /*.change-time + .time-range__tooltip {
 display: block;
}
.no-change-time + .time-range__tooltip {
 display: none;
}*/
  .dnone {
    display: none;
  }
  .cal {
    dispaly: block;
  }
  .c-date input[type="button"] {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    color: #656565;
  }
  .choose-date {
    line-height: 21px;
  }
  .time-range__tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #969595;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 115px;
    top: -5px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 110px;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 4;
    /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
  }
  .time-range__tooltip::before {
    content: "";
    left: -16px;
    top: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid #f6f6f6;
    z-index: 6;
  }
  .time-range__tooltip::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid #969595;
    z-index: 5;
    left: -16px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  .time-range__selected {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .time-range__selected {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #969595;
    color: #969595;
  }
  /*modal choose time*/
  .ch-time__modal {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 102px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    right: -25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-bordfer-radius: 3px;
  }
  .ch-time__modal::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: -19px;
    bottom: 83px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #f6f6f6;
    z-index: 6;
  }
  .ch-time__modal::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: -21px;
    bottom: 82px;
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid #e0e0e0;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .ch-time__wrapcontent {
    position: relative;
  }
  .hasDatepicker {
    display: initial;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .choinfoblock {
      padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    }
    .choinfoblock .control-label {
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .choinfoblock input[type="text"],
    .choinfoblock input[type="email"],
    .choinfoblock textarea,
    .choinfoblock select {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .delivery-group .control-label {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .delivery-group .delivdata {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .chotab_content .delivery .delivery__row:nth-of-type(1) {
      display: none;
    }
    .delivery__cell {
      float: left;
    }
    /*.mobile .column-2 {
  display: none;
 }*/
    /*.data-range-mobile {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%;
     float: left;
    }*/
    .open-calendar,
    .time-range__wrap {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .column-3 {
      display: none;
    }
    .column-1a {
      display: block;
    }
    .delivery__cell {
      padding: 5px 7px 5px 0;
    }
    .column-1 {
      width: auto;
    }
    .column-2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .time-range__wrap {
      /*float: right;*/
      /*padding-right: 10%;*/
      margin-left: 2%;
    }
    .open-calendar {
      padding-left: 7%;
    }
    .day::after,
    .date::after {
      display: none;
    }
    .column-1 {
      /*width: 150px;*/
      width: 70%;
    }
    .del-link {
      top: 0;
    }
    .del-link::after {
      display: none;
    }
    .time-range__tooltip {
      top: 36px;
      left: 0;
    }
    .time-range__tooltip::before {
      left: 45px;
      top: -20px;
      border-right: none;
      border: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #f6f6f6;
    }
    .time-range__tooltip::after {
      border: 11px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 11px solid #969595;
      left: 44px;
      top: -22px;
    }
    .main-column {
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .choinfoblock {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .row.control-group {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    #order_form .control-label {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
    .choinfoblock,
    .choinfoblock .control-group .control-label {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .choinfoblock .control-group .control-label + div,
    .row.delivery-group .delivdata {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .choinfoblock.chosubmission {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group > .control-label {
      display: none;
    }
    .choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group > .control-label + div > label {
      padding-top: 0;
      margin-top: -20px;
    }
    #order_form .chosubmission label {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: -20px;
    }
    .offer__inner {
      margin-left: 3px;
    }
    .br-oi {
      display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .chosubmission .form-actions input[type="submit"] {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 15px;
      left: 0;
    }
    .row.delivery-group {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .chotab_item {
      margin-left: 0 !important;
      margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
    #order_form input[type="text"],
    #order_form input[type="email"],
    #order_form textarea,
    #order_form select {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .delivery__table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .time-range__wrap {
      top: -8px;
      left: 0;
    }
    .column-1a {
      display: none;
    }
    .del-link::after,
    .day::after,
    .date::after {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .open-calendar {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
  }
  .delivery-group .control-label {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #656565;
  }
  .type_pay__sub-info {
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 12px;
  }
  .paytypes .type-pay {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
  }
  .choinfoblock.paytypes {
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  }
  .paytypes .control-group {
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
  .type-pay__inner {
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #303030;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group > .control-label {
    display: none;
  }
  .rules_ofert {
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .choinfoblock.chosubmission .control-group .control-label + div {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .br-oi {
    display: none;
  }
  .chotab_item {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .chotabs > .chotab.pick_upcho:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".time-range__selected, .close_tooltip").on("click", function(e) {


        $(".time-range__tooltip").addClass("dnone");

        var toolTip = $(this).parent().next(".time-range__tooltip");
        if (toolTip.hasClass("dnone")) {
          toolTip.removeClass("dnone");

          var firstClick = true;
          $(document).bind("click.myEvent", function(e) {
            if (!firstClick && $(e.target).closest(".time-range__tooltip").length == 0) {
              toolTip.addClass("dnone");
              $(document).unbind("click.myEvent");
            }
            firstClick = false;
          });
        }

        e.preventDefault();

      });

      $(".time-radio").on("click", function(e) {
        var newTimeRangeText = $(this).next().text();
        $(this).parents('.time-range__wrap').find('.time-range__selected').text(newTimeRangeText);

      });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chotab_content">
    <div class="delivery radio">
      <div class="delivery__table">


        <div class="delivery__row">

          <div class="delivery__cell column-2">
            <div class="open-calendar">
              <a class="c-date">
                <i class="o-date"></i>
                <input class="choose-date" type="button" value="Сегодня">
                <div class="under-line"></div>



              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="time-range__wrap">
              <div class="time-range">
                <i class="choose-time"></i>
                <span class="time-range__selected">Выбрать время</span>
              </div>

              <ul class="time-range__tooltip dnone">
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-1" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-1">10.00-18.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-2" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-2">18.00-21.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-3" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-3">10.00-15.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-4" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-4">14.00-18.00</label>
                </li>
                <a class="close_tooltip">закрыть</a>
              </ul>

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="delivery__cell column-3">
            250 руб.
          </div>




        </div>

        <div class="delivery__row">




          <div class="delivery__cell column-2">
            <div class="open-calendar">
              <a class="c-date">
                <i class="o-date"></i>
                <input class="choose-date" type="button" value="Сегодня">
                <div class="under-line"></div>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="time-range__wrap">
              <div class="time-range">
                <i class="choose-time"></i>
                <span class="time-range__selected" href="">Выбрать время</span>
              </div>

              <ul class="time-range__tooltip dnone">
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-5" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-5">10.00-18.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-6" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-6">18.00-21.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-7" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-7">10.00-15.00</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input name="delivery-time-range" id="time-select-8" class="time-radio" type="radio">
                  <label for="time-select-8">14.00-18.00</label>
                </li>

                <a class="close_tooltip">закрыть</a>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="delivery__cell column-3">
            500 руб.
          </div>
        </div>





      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: вместо parents лучше closest

Comment: @gru да, без практики быстро забывается))

Comment: :-D именно поэтому я здесь

Comment: Да, согласен каши много ))